# How to prevent a java class/type from appearing in graphql schema when using smallrye graphql?

Tags: java, graphql, smallrye

I have an "internal use" response class (type) that I don't want in GraphQL schema. I tried NOT tagging it with @Type annotation but it doesn't help. I have found a github thread where people are requesting @Ignore annotation for classes (it already exists for fields) but it has been stale for a year. Is there any non-hacky way to exclude a type from GraphQL schema?